# Multiple Emails Validations

Tags: javascript, validation

I have an email id field in which multiple email ids have to be entered seperated by commas. How to perform validations of all the email ids using JavaScript in a jsp page?

Comment: By "email id" you mean email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be help you for Validate multiple email id's using javascript

```
 <html>
<title>email validation</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    // Validate Email .
    function validateEmail(field) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}$/;
       return (regex.test(field)) ? true : false;
    }
    function validateMultipleEmailsCommaSeparated(emailcntl) {
        var seperator = ';';

        var value = emailcntl;

        if (value != '') {
            var result = value.split(seperator);

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                if (result[i] != '') {

                    if (!validateEmail(result[i])) {
                        alert('Please check, `' + result[i] + '` email addresses not valid!');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
            <input type="button" onclick="validateMultipleEmailsCommaSeparated(email.value);"
                value="check Email" /><br />
            <div id="errorDiv" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thnx for the solution. It works perfect. I have a query ..what if the user enters a different separator say ',' instead if ';' ,then the whole length of the email id will be taken as a string such as [ajay@yahoo.com,abhay@gamil.com]....it won't split it. and the validation would fail.

Comment: it's gives alert message. if you want separator as ',' then change the  var seperator = ';'; to  var seperator = ',';